# Hex annotation on MSDN site

Tags: hex, msdn, domaindatasource

**I fail to understand the hex annotation at the MSDN site**

On the following MSDN site: [DDS file spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

there is a table at *dwFlags*. dwFlags is a DWORD (4 Bytes or 0x00000000)

**Question: The hex annotations for a value (e.g.) 0x800000 are confusing me, which bit (of the 32) do I have to flip?**

Please 'translate' the value coloumn of the source (just 8 values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x800000` is the same as `100000000000000000000000` in binary.

```
 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 ^  ^    ...       ^    ^    ^
23 20    ...       8    4    0   = bit position
```

So it's the 23rd bit.

For `dwFlags` does this mean:

```
0x1      = 1
0x2      = 10
0x4      = 100
0x8      = 1000
0x1000   = 1000000000000
0x20000  = 100000000000000000
0x80000  = 10000000000000000000
0x800000 = 100000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Now I get it, I mixed decimal and hexadecimal up. Thank you.